# Cross Docker Communication - Get a Jmap dump from another container

Tags: java, docker, containers, jmap

I've been working on this for a few weeks but now I'm kind of stuck.

I currently have two docker containers. Both of them are running the following java version:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'd need to be able to make `Container1` get a `jmap` dump from `Container2` and dump it locally.

I've been using `strace` on Container1, and I can attach the java process running on #2, but when I use `jmap`, I get the following error:

> futex(0x7f6f4c80c9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 52, NULL51: Unable to open socket
>   file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded.

I know the signal GETS to Container2 since I can end processes just fine, but what else should I be looking out for?

Thanks!